# my page is not redirecting properly

Tags: php, google-chrome, yii

I have a popup which shows up if the user is not logged in. It contains a cancel link, a form to enter details, and a forget password link. My problem is when the user comes back from the forget password link and clicks the cancel link, it takes them back to the forget password page.

Here is my code.

```
  <div class="contactForm_new" id="popUpDiv"  style="display:none;">
                    <!--<div  class="lightBlue heading" >Tell us your Buy Requirement</div>-->
                    <div class="blueLightBG heading" style="text-align: left;
                         padding-left: 2%;background-color:#009bcb ">Enter Password  <a href="<?php echo $return_url ?>"> <span class=" dpbl fr mainSp cr_bt2 p_a closeTrigger closePopup href"  style="position: absolute; display: block;"></span></a></div>
                    <form method="post" class="contactF" id="login-form">
                        <input type="hidden" value=""  name="offerid">   
                        <input type="hidden" value="" name="refvalue">
                        <input type="hidden" value="" name="tenderid"> 
                        <input type="hidden" value="" name="item_id"> 
                        <input type="hidden" value="" name="pid">  
                        <input type="hidden" value="sd" name="ref">
                        <input type="hidden" value="1" name="isLogRequest">  
                        <input type="hidden" name="iso" id="iso" value="<?php echo $details['iso'] ?>">  
                        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $return_en_url ?>"  id="p_address" name="p_address"> 



                        <div class="errorMessage" id="errorUsername"></div>
                        <input type="hidden" name="diff_usr" value="Y">
                        <input type="hidden" value="Y" name="diff_usr">
                        <input class="pd3 textlogin_new" name="LoginForm[password]" id="LoginForm_password" type="password">
                        <div class="errorMessage" id="errorPassword"></div>


                        <div style="padding:15px 0;text-align:center">
                            <span id="imgprcp" class="fl" style=" display: none;  text-align: center;margin-left:50%;"><img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->params['hostName'] ?>/images/ind.gif" alt="Proceeding"></span>
                            <input id="btnSubmit"  type="button" name="yt0" value="Proceed" class="redBtn_new" >
                        </div>

                        <div class="mb3per" style="display:block">
                            <p class="k7_new" style="position:absolute;" >
                                <a class="k7_new" id="forgotpass"  style="position:relative;" href="<?php echo Yii::app()->params['hostName'] ?>/forgotpass/?ref=<?php echo $ref ?>&p=<?php echo $return_en_url ?>" >Forgot Password?</a>
                            </p>

                        </div>   
                    </form>


                </div>
```

Can anybody suggest what am I doing wrong? All of my URLs are formed correctly.This problem is coming in only chrome browser.In another browser it is working fine

Comment: Where's the cancel button in this code, I can't see it?

Comment: just next to enter password. i had given a link and a span

Comment: @vector is this an caching issue